# Golang command arguments empty causing error

Tags: go, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a go program and I need to use command arguments. However if I don't pass arguments when I run the executable or `go run gosite.go` the code it does the following runtime error.

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.panic(0x80c8540, 0x816d4b7)
/usr/lib/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:266 +0xac
main.main()
/home/jacob/github/gosite/src/github.com/zachdyer/gosite/gosite.go:11 +0x168
```

The error is found on line 11. So my question is am I using the `os.Args` in the wrong way? Does this need to be initialized in a different way? Also why does it seem to be going in an infinite loop there? If I pass in an argument the program runs without any errors and prints the argument.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

var root string

func main() {
    command := os.Args[1]
    if command != "" {
        fmt.Println(command)
    } else {
        command = ""
        fmt.Println("No command given")
    }

    createDir("public")
    createDir("themes")
}

func createDir(dir string) {
    root = "../../../../"
    err := os.Mkdir(root + dir, 0777)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First check the length of the `os.Args` slice and only index up to its length - 1:

```
if len(os.Args) > 1 {
    command := os.Args[1]
    // do something with command
} else {
    // No arguments were specified!
}
```

> `os.Args` hold the command-line arguments, starting with the program name.

`os.Args[0]` is the program name. *If* there are arguments, they go to `Args[1]`, `Args[2]`...

If no arguments were specified, the length of `os.Args` will be 1 and will hold only the program name.

Also for easier and more sophisticated arguments handling check out the [`flag`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) package.

Answer (score -1):

You have to check first if os.Args exist and how big it is , before you should access it. This is best practive in ervery programming language using arrays.

This should work:

```
func main() {

    if (os.Args != nil && len(os.Args) > 1) {
        command := os.Args[1]
        if command != "" {
            fmt.Println(command)
        } else {
            command = ""
            fmt.Println("No command given")
        }
    }
    createDir("public")
    createDir("themes")
}
```

Depending on all that fault-finder's here that only can go, and had readen the handbook here the correct only go specific version for handling the input arguments. (A Note as I sad before, I don't develop go, I answered by best practice for handling arrays, to prefend out of range error):

```
func main() {

    if (len(os.Args) > 1) {
        command := os.Args[1]
        if command != "" {
            fmt.Println(command)
        } else {
            command = ""
            fmt.Println("No command given")
        }
    }
    createDir("public")
    createDir("themes")
}
```

1. It is not checking on nil anymore, because os.Args always are initialized and holds the app name on index 0
2. It checks the len greater then 1 to make sure that index 1 exist. Or in other words the user has entered arguments and os.Args has more entries then only the app name.

Comment: `os.Args` starts with the program name, so you should check `len() > 1`. Also no need to test if it's `nil` (redundant), the builtin `len()` function works on `nil` slices as well.

Comment: I'm not developing go ;) As I said, my solution is best practice for every array with unkown origin. So when you wanna be clean and correct, do it like I did and ignore that go handle this for you ;)

Comment: I don't think that's a very good advice, basically you're saying _"forget in which language you're coding, and only use the common subset of all languages"_. Doing so you will end up unnecessarily complicated, ugly and non-idiomatic code. Also the `len() > 1` check is mandatory, checking only `len() > 0` you may end up with the same error if no arguments is specified because `len() > 1` is always true as `Args` contains the program name, but if no arguments were specified, `Args[1]` will result in a : `runtime error: index out of range`

Comment: As you say ;) Keep on go, I keep on applied computer science :D

Comment: This will still panic the same way as in the question. `len(os.Args) > 0` is always true, and doesn't check for any command line arguments.

Comment: `len(os.Args) > 1` is not always true, at least in Linux and macOS. If you compile a go program and then write a C program to exec it with `execl("/path/to/exec", NULL)`, it will have no arguments at all, not even the executable name.